# html5 audioplayer refreshed through innerhtml issue with preventdefault

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, html5-audio

building a website using Google App Script web apps.
have a code that fetch a playlist acording to search keywords. results are formated as html list and inserted into div on page using innerhtml.

I have a script for the playlist that include preventdefault and highlighting of played track

```js
audioPlayer();
        function audioPlayer(){
            var currentSong = 0;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
            $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
                $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
                currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
                $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
                
            });
            
            
        }
```

the script works if I load playlist with the page initailly but once I update the playlist through the innerhtml method (with new playlist) i seem to lose the script unctionality - when clicking on one of the tracks in the playlist it deaulting to play the track in a new page as per browser defaults.

I have tried to include the audioplayer inside the innerhtml method (so it refreshes with the playlist) and also to keep it static in another div on the main page - none works...

```js
   function fnResults(resultsData){

  // resultsData is html formated list of mp3 files, "playlistContainer" is the div being populated by the innerHtml
  
  document.getElementById("playlistContainer").innerHTML = '<audio class="AudioPlayer" src="" controls id="audioPlayer"></audio><ul id="playlist"><li class="current-song">' + resultsData +'</ul>';
  
  //in this example the audioplayer is being loaded with the playlist
  
  }
  
       // this is the script to control the audioPlayer
       
       audioPlayer();
        function audioPlayer(){
            var currentSong = 0;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
            $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
                $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
                currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
                $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
            });
        }
```

and this is a sample value of "resultsData":

```html
<a href=http://www.digitalhistory.uh.edu/music/marines_hymn_us_marine_band1998.mp3>1st Track Name - Artist Name</a></li><li><a href=http://www.digitalhistory.uh.edu/music/marines_hymn_us_marine_band1998.mp3>2nd Track Name - Artist Name</a></li>
```

Comment: You need to set the click handler after updating the playlist.

Comment: thanks - tbh am not sure exactly how to do it - i tried adding it to the js file like this :  $("#playlistContainer").click(function() {
  audioPlayer();  where playlistContainer is the div id containing the playlist but it did not work

Comment: Your full code isn't there, so I can't say with certainty that this is exactly what you need to do, but I assume you just need to run `$("#playlist li a").click(function(e) { ... })` after you update the playlist. (Don't actually write "...", it's just my abbreviation of that code block.)

Comment: tried it few ways but still no luck - not sure I understand the function the click triggers... <br/>I will update the original post wiith full code

Comment: added script in original post before modifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code in how you're listening to `click` event.
So now you have:

`$("#playlist li a").click(function(e){`

It means *"Now take all elements that are `#playlist li a` and set click listener on them".*
Elements that appear in DOM later, when you're updating the playlist, will not be taken in account.

The possible solution is to set click litener to `document` (aka event delegation). Just slightly change your code line from above:

`$(document).on("click", "#playlist li a", function(e){`

So every time you click on any element, the element will be checked if it is `#playlist li a` and if it is, run the specified function.

For more details please look at [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

> **Delegated event handlers** have the advantage that they can process events from *descendant elements* that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated event handlers to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: fantastic! worked , thank you... but just for ref it only works when the audioplayer is loaded with page rather than when its inserted with innerHtml